# flywaydb : MView Refresh Failing

Tags: oracle11g, flyway

I am trying to refresh Materialised view using Flyway DB but below error coming
Help....is this supported or not?

Below SQL

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW TEST.TBL_M_V REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND;

EXECUTE DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('TEST.TBL_M_V','C');

ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW TEST.TBL_M_V NEVER REFRESH;
```

Below error coming

```
ERROR: Migration of schema "TEST" to version 4.1 failed! Please restore backu
ps and roll back database and code!
ERROR:
Migration V4_1__MViewRefresh_Test.sql failed
--------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 900
Message    : ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Location   : C:/dev/flyway-3.1/sql/V4_1__MViewRefresh_Test.sql
Line       : 8
Statement  : EXECUTE DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('TEST.TBL_M_V','C')
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, it is not a Flyway issue. The Oracle JDBC driver refused your statement.

This is the correct syntax you should use:

`BEGIN
   DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('TEST.TBL_M_V','C');
END;`

Comment: Thanks Axel let me give it a try and confirm :)

Comment: I used below in one file:  ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW TEST.TBL_M_V REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND;

BEGIN
DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('TEST.TBL_M_V','C');
END;

ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW TEST.TBL_M_V NEVER REFRESH;

Comment: Cant we add three statements in one file where refresh is doing we have to modify refresh type for that view everytime